# Self upvoting documentation posts (examples)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, documentation

I created [an example on Stack Overflow documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/740/xml-documentation-comments/2521/simple-method-annotation#t=201607190620205221779). And then I was able to **self upvote** this example.

Is that ok?

Comment: You're definitely in the right place to report bugs or provide feedback in general about documentation (just use the documentation tag, as you did). Looks like you did get +2 rep for it, I don't _think_ that's by design, the devs will have a look soon.

Comment: @TimPost I seem to recall this being discussed on the original docs meta site - are those questions still searchable anywhere? (Seems they're [still visible](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/july-11th-announcements?noredirect=1) if you know the URL and append `noredirect=1` to the URL)

Comment: Not sure if it matters much but you should know that link is broken

Comment: From what I remember from the documentation beta site, you can up vote your own post, but you are supposed to *not* get rep for it.

Comment: @BrianHowell The link will likely only work if you're part of the documentation private beta, it's soon to be opened up to a public beta.

Comment: @TimPost He got +2 for the [edit being approved](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/6486). He got nothing for the upvote.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Good call. Inexperienced low-rep users like me don't know these things

Comment: @BrianHowell We were all there once - it's good that you're just active on meta at all :)

Comment: Yaar... You documentation folks all having fun, and I'm still on the sidelines :/

Comment: @Zizouz212 You're not missing much. It's pretty deserted an nobody knows what are they supposed to be doing.

Comment: You must've clicked on the upvote button for yourself by accident when you first discovered this? ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

At first it doesn't look legit... at least I thought so.

But let's look at it closer:

- You get (or lose) *no* reputation by voting for yourself. (Moreover, there're no badges for nice/good/great examples, probably just yet). There's no competition for the best example on a *same* sub-topic, you just improve the existing ones, and post only if the sub-topic is different. (expanding this sentence in the next point)
- A documentation example is, unlike a post, a thing that is always *supposed* to be contributed to, be improved, and always offer the *best* way of solving the problem (now look at the posts: in case with answers, it's encouraged to post another answer if you're going to use the technique different from the one used in existing answers). If you don't think the docs example suggests the best practice currently, you either propose a change or request an improvement, but you don't go and post a different example. Mostly, this is not the case with the posts (probably except for Community Wiki ones), where a new answer could be better or worse than another one.
- The contributors to your example *do* get the reputation when you vote your example up, and it's really important. You may have not written the best example, but your example, having been improved, became really good. Would be strange if you couldn't upvote that example just because you posted it.
- Votes in the documentation don't only show if that sub-topic is descibed in a good/bad way, but also help to determine the most *vital* (and fisrt-to-learn) sub-topic in that topic (uh, needs rewording). That said, there are no topics which shouldn't be learned at all, so I wouldn't downvote the sub-topic because of it having small importance, but rather upvote another one.

Comment: wait - you can get rep from SO documentation? is it the same kind of rep on SO main? If so, I need to get in on this delicious reputation for all my bounties...

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC You betcha!

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC That's not a green-light to go and start adding below par content though, just a preemptive warning.

Comment: @Lankymart I'm never gonna do that - profit and contribution is always the best!

Comment: @Lankymart Just take a look at this article I wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/1693/arrayfield-a-postgresql-specific-field#t=201607221545254347368

Comment: self upvote for example give one badge "Backer" :D

Comment: @nicael i have experienced the same problem but in my case, i get a reputation for some time and then when I posted a question here then it taken back from my account.Here is [my-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354188/should-you-be-allowed-to-up-vote-your-own-posted-documentation) so can you help me to understand?