# Documentation Proposed Changes Queue

Tags: feature-request, documentation, proposed-changes

Surprise! It's [Public Beta for Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328405/documentation-has-entered-public-beta), and we're getting *lots* of contributions. This is Great! But we need to accept these in a timely manner, to make room for additional improvements without worrying about dual editing of the same Examples.

I'm no longer able to handle all the items in my inbox as they come in, so I've toned down my Subscription Frequency to make sure that Q&A Comments do not get drowned out.

Since I am knowledgeable in many tags (but not all of them), and working out of my Inbox is no longer practical, I'm going to want some kind of centralized queue.

I found [this hidden gem](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/all?tab=proposedchanges), which collects all Proposed Changes into a single place. I can visually scan for the tags I'm knowledgeable in, but I'd like to post a request to:

1. Allow me to filter the list to my Favorite Documentation Tags.
2. Show the date of the Proposed Change. (so I can work oldest first)

Frankly, I wouldn't mind having a way to input this into the URL as an intermediate solution. I tried replacing `all` with `java+css` but that didn't work. :-)