# Cannot commit to proposal, answers on non-Stack Overflow site are not counted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation

I want to commit to the Puppet proposal here:
https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/puppet

But it tells me that I don't meet the criteria of:
"With at least 1 positively scored answer in [puppet]"

I do have that on Server Fault; it's actually one of my top 10 tags I write answers for.

Answer (score 1):

Tags aren't aware of each other's existence cross-site.

Furthermore:

> [right now we're focusing on Stack Overflow. Once Documentation is "known to work" we'll start thinking about other sites.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328405/documentation-has-entered-public-beta#comment369176_328405)