# What if I don't know the release date?

Tags: support, documentation

When trying to add versions to Docs, it says:

> Versions must be formatted as a table, where the first column is the version name and the last column is a YYYY-MM-DD style release date.

I'm trying to add some versioning to [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), and I'm starting with PCRE (which has 2 versions). I have a date for the newer one, but I only know that the first one was released in [1997](http://www.ukuug.org/events/linux2007/2007/papers/Hazel.pdf). [Or 1998](http://oss-watch.ac.uk/resources/cs-exim). I can't find anything more specific than "summer 199(7|8)".

Things like dates often get lost in history. What should I do? Should I make up a date or can I bypass this requirement?

And why is it necessary to provide a date *down to the **exact day*** anyway? It's hard for me  to find this information, given the subject.

---

In the meantime, just assume that PCRE will be re-released in the year 9999.

> [image: 9999-01-01]

Comment: As far I'm aware regex has no versions, just a bunch of implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's OK to estimate (summer can be June 1st if you want).

We need release dates so we can order versions when we display them.  Too many things don't use semantic versioning for us to just use the version names, and editing makes relying on "markdown order" tricky.