# Documentation beta end date

Tags: discussion, documentation

Is there an official end date for the Documentation Beta Phase? I have looked on Meta SO for the end date of beta but I haven't found anything.

Comment: What difference does it make? The foundation of it is live and anyone can contribute

Comment: I suspect that it will be out of beta in 6-8 weeks

Comment: There's probably no fixed date. Nor should there be - there's way too much that needs addressing first.

Comment: It will be ready when it is ready. Surely there is no other answer than that?

Answer (score 7):

According to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328405/4751173), dated July 21st, it will take at least a couple of months:

> Documentation is in beta, so we know we’re going to learn a lot in the coming months.

If there was a known end date, it probably would've been mentioned there.

Anyway, the beta-status should not matter. Gmail has been in beta from 2004 until 2009, that didn't keep people from using it. Documentation will be in beta as least as long as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNcgw.png) happens, plus [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/295232).

Comment: Oh, I see you've removed the [documentation] tag from your ignored tags. I cannot imagine what could have motivated that. It's not like anything's gotten any clearer on that front.

Comment: @CodyGray it's still ignored, but with the 'gray out questions' option.