# Clarity in Docs tour as to rep limit for accepting changes

Tags: feature-request, documentation, reputation, documentation-proposals

There doesn't seem to be anywhere on the Docs site that explains how accepting changes work, especially with regards to reputation.

After asking for a while on the Docs chat, someone [pointed out](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32587553#32587553) that you need 100+ reputation to cast a vote (and then linked to [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes))

It would have saved me (and I would imagine quite a few others) a lot of confusion to have at least some of this information in the [Docs tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation) or somewhere less hidden away (I couldn't find an easy way to get to the documentation post from the Docs homepage)

Comment: The lack of documentation, much less *accessible* documentation, [has been a problem with Documentation since day one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328405/documentation-has-entered-public-beta#comment369204_328405). Irony aside, it would be a very good idea to add a link to this information in the Tour so people can actually find it. Did you know that Documentation also [feebly attempts to document itself](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/documentation/topics)? Me neither.

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't know about that, even linking to the /documentation/documentation from the tour would make it more accessible, to both people wanting answers and people wanting to contribute to questions about Docs.

Comment: Yeah, it is rather interesting that the "Ask Question" button Meta is the go-to resource for getting help on using Documentation. If only there was a website where we could go to ask our *programming* questions and get instant answers...that'd be a really cool model.