# Add a check box "I do not want reputation for this edit" to the Edit Interface

Tags: feature-request, documentation, reputation

This feature resquest aims to solve :

- [Don't give me reputation points for making an edit to a Documentation topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328866/3205529)
- [Can we please introduce more reputation limits for examples on Documentation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329940/3205529)

One simple  solution is :

1. to add a checkbox to the editor interface with label "I do not want reputation for this edit". **If the editor checks this box he will never receive reputation for this edit.**
2. During the review process, reviewers can see if the author has chosen this option or not. In doing so, reviewers (so the community) will be able to estimate if the edit is significant enough or not to get reputation. Then they can choose to Accept or to reject the Edit with more information.
3. Maybe add a Documentation Altruist badge ?

I think it can also increase the number of correct edit because, sometimes you don't want that people think you are mining reputation , because you don't, and then you don't correct minor errors for this reason.

Ps: This proposal comes form [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329965/3205529)

Comment: What's the point? This doesn't solve anything for users that game the system, and further increases the rift between those who actually do work.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, from my point of view it does because, reviewers (and not robots) will be able to estimate the trade-off between substantial edit and reputation.

Comment: You mean similar to Wikipedia's ["Minor edit"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Minor_edit)? I suppose, but I still think the best solution is awarding flat reputation. What constitutes a minor change is still subjective.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes, something similar to "minor edit". Anyway, let the community vote to see if it seems to be a good idea or not.

Comment: I want to add my 2 cents to this suggestion: how about if the Documentation reviewer interface get more options instead of approve/reject, something like: Substantial improvement, Minor improvement, No improvement. Then edits approved as "substantial" will grant the contributor "full rep gains", while minor will only give the +2 and perhaps have your avatar added to the contributors list (possibly at 70-80% size). This way, it's immediately visible who contributed how much, and rep will be distributed more fairly. OTOH, some people will possibly get mad that their edits are considered "minor".