# Should you be allowed to up vote your own posted documentation?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, documentation

> **I am aware that you cannot up vote your own post, be it a question or an answer.**

But I just recently posted something in the documentation section for CodeIgniter on StackOverflow. I up voted my post and it worked.

I didn't get the message saying **You can't vote for your own post**

So I am curious to know is that allowed or is this a bug that needs to be fixed?

I am editing this question because it looks like my post is deleted. here I am adding a screenshot of my approved post in the documentation.

#### So Please can any one tell me what's going on. Why my post is get deleted after approve?

[image]

I am also adding that screenshot of reputation which I get while voting for upvoting my documentation.

**For voting duplicate:** ok, may be it's a duplicate question but in my case, i get the reputation for upvoting my self and the after posting this issue on meta My reputation get removed which I get from that up vote. I understand it that I can't get the reputation for upvoting my self and I didn't want that but it happens that I get +5 reputation and then -5 after posting it here. So is this a bug or anything else just want to know that. that's all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: **$** *cha ching*

Comment: @Ihazkode I am not understanding what you are saying?

Comment: @ankitsuthar They are joking, making the _cha ching_ sound because they can get rep for nothing. Anyway, I think this is a bug, could you link the documentation you're on about please.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/codeigniter/7398/form-validation/32703/saving-sets-of-validation-rules-to-a-config-file#t=20170801101802433) but I think that my post is get deleted. i have a screen shot should i post it here. ? @George

Comment: @ankitsuthar you can do but I'm assuming it's [this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/codeigniter/7398/form-validation/32703/saving-sets-of-validation-rules-to-a-config-file#t=20170801101802433)

Comment: here is the proof that i have posted and get approved in documentation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/151743) @George

Comment: can any one please tell me why I am not able to ask another question here?

Comment: @NathanOliver ok may be it's duplicate but if you read that answer of the question (accepted one) it says you didn't get any reputation for it in my case i have get 5+ for that and then it reversed after I posted here.